# How to reset UIButton image when I have multiple images - swift?

Tags: swift, uibutton

I have UIButton called menuButton which has a customClass where it sets multiple images and I have a dropDown menu when we click on it. So based on menu selected I want to menuButton to change the image.

This is my code:

```
public enum MenuItems: String {
  case menu1 = "menu1"
  case menu2 = "menu2"
  case menu3 = "menu3"
}

func layoutView() {
     menuButton.setImages(normalImage: "triangleImage",
                                  image: "menu1",
                                  selectedImage: "closeImage")
    menuButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(menuItemTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.addSubview(menuButton)
}

func menuItemTapped(sender: UIView) {
    guard let title = sender.accessibilityIdentifier else { return }
    let style = MenuItems(rawValue: title)
    
    switch style {
    case .menu1:
      menuButton.setImages(normalImage: "triangleImage",
                                  image: "menu1",
                                  selectedImage: "closeImage")
    case .menu2:
       menuButton.setImages(normalImage: "triangleImage",
                                  image: "menu2",
                                  selectedImage: "closeImage")
    case .menu3:
       menuButton.setImages(normalImage: "triangleImage",
                                  image: "menu3",
                                  selectedImage: "closeImage")
    default:
      break
    }
}

class MultipleImageButton: UIButton {

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
  }

  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  func setImages(normalImage: UIImage, image: UIImage, selectedImage: UIImage) {
    setImage(normalImage, for: .normal)
    setImage(selectedImage, for: .selected)
    imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0_5x, left: 1x, bottom: 0_5x, right: (bounds.maxX - 55))
    contentHorizontalAlignment = .right

    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x + 4x,
                                              y: (titleLabel?.bounds.midY ?? 0) + 1x,
                                                  width: 5x,
                                              height: frame.height - 2_5x))

    imageView.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    imageView.image = image
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    addSubview(imageView)
  }
}
```

Using the above code I'm able to change the button image but its adding image on top of another. For eg: I click on menu 2, it adds menu2 image on top of menu1 image. How do i clear the image?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the tap method in following way :

```
@objc func menuItemTapped(sender: UIButton!) {
    guard let title = sender.accessibilityIdentifier else { return }
    let style = MenuItems(rawValue: title)
    switch style {
       case .menu1:
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "menu1.png"), forState: 
        .normal)
       case .menu2:
          sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "menu2.png"), forState: 
          .normal)
       case .menu3:
          sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "menu3.png"), forState: 
          .normal)
       default:
          break
      }
    }
```